# intermittent 401 from google cloud build api Oauth issues

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Up until last week, our calls to GCP have been working 100%.  Last week something happened and we now get 401 intermittently (well, more like over and over and then it magically starts working again).  I have not had it fail from my local machine yet and only in cloud run.

Here is the error

```
json error='{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

We want talking to google cloud build to work locally OR in cloud run so we generated a json token.  If expired, I would assume, we get ALL 401's not intermittent though AND why is it working from my local machine?

We are using an access token which we create from a json file.  I   forgot how we created this json file though.  Still digging for that info.

Comment: Without details on the exact request that generated this error, we can only guess. Recreate your question by showing the code that generates the OAuth Tokens and makes the HTTP request. Include the full HTTP request with headers.

Comment: Adding to John's comment above, has there been any new deployments made since the error started to appear, if not, it might be interesting to open a Bug Report in [Google Cloud's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=190802&template=0), since it could be a problem with Cloud Build itself, and if not, they might be able to discover what is wrong in your project while troubleshooting.

Comment: We figured out the issue(posted an answer) HOWEVER, I am still not sure why or when the *.json file expires.  Does it ever expire?  I mean, like an ssl cert, it should expire in a year, right? or no?

Answer (score 1):

So we found out, we had moved this code into our constructor

```
        GoogleCredentials scoped = credential.createScoped(scopes);
        scoped.refreshIfExpired();
        AccessToken accessToken = scoped.getAccessToken();
```

Moving that back to the request path and refreshing every request(probably need to fix that eventually) fixes this issue.

I am still curious though "Why I don't have to refresh my *.json file every now and then?"  I assume if my *.json stays the same for 1 year, that starts to become a security risk, right?

thanks,
Dean